# If a potential function exists for a certain vector field, is it then automatically conservative?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I know that if a vector field is conservative, a potential function exists, but does this relation also hold the other way around? In other words, does a potential function exist for a certain vector field if and only if the field in question is conservative?

Comment: are you talking of scalar potential specifically?

Comment: What's your [definition of "conservative vector field"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say a vector field $\vec A$ has the potential $\phi$.

So we can write that $\vec A=\nabla \phi$

Now, line integral around the field from $M$ to $N$
$= \int_M^N \vec A \cdot \vec{dl}$ 
$= \int_M^N \nabla \phi \cdot \vec{dl}$ 
$= \int_M^N \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\hat i+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\hat j+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\hat k\right)  \cdot (dx\hat i+dy\hat j+dz\hat k)$ 
$= \int_M^N \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}dy+ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}dz\right)$ 
$= \int_M^N d\phi$ 
$=\phi(M)-\phi(N)$

which is independent of the path joining $M$ and $N$.

So such *vector field*s having *scalar potential* are *conservative*.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : it seems you are looking for the "easy" implication that if a vector field is derived from a potential then it's conservative, which is always true. My answer actually says that what you are taking for granted (the reverse implication) is false in general. I guess you are working in a case where it's true, but it may interest you that there are restrictions.

---

It depends on the geometry of the space upon which the vector space is defined. If it's defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then yes. If it's (for instance) $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, then no.

This is because a conservative vector field is basically a closed $1$-form, and a field that comes from a potential is basically an exact $1$-form, and closed $1$-forms are exact precisely when the first de Rham cohomology group is trivial. This happens for instance on a contractible space (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$), but not on any space.

It's actually a purely topological condition : it's equivalent to the fact that $\pi_1(X)^{ab}$ is a torsion group, where $X$ is the space on which the vector field is defined.

Comment: Hint: $d^2=0$ !  So any exact form is closed.

Comment: Be careful, @captainlama : it appears we are dealing with the easy implication!

Comment: Of coruse, the de Rham complex is, well, a complex. You did not read carefully what I wrote : the converse is in general, false.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli well it is written "if and only if" in the question.

Comment: @CaptainLama It is also written "I know that if a vector field is conservative, a potential function exists, but does this relation also hold the other way around?".

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I did not read carefully enough too ! Well, as far as I'm concerned this is false (or rather this is true precisely in the conditions written in my answer). I'll leave my answer as a reference for future readers even though it seems it does not truly answer the OP's question.